# Invalid conversion from (some-class)** to void**

Tags: c++, void-pointers

I am new to this community and new to C++, which is where i am trying to get my program to run.
I am trying out an exercise in Thinking in C++ by Bruce Eckel, and there, I am to use his implementation of a Stack and change its constructor so that it takes as its arguments an array of pointers to objects and the size of that array.  The constructor should then move through the array and push each pointer onto the stack.
Here is his implementation of Stack, which is available at his website:

```
//: C04:Stack.cpp {O}
// From Thinking in C++, 2nd Edition
// Available at http://www.BruceEckel.com
// (c) Bruce Eckel 2000
// Copyright notice in Copyright.txt
// Linked list with nesting
#include "Stack.h"
#include "require.h"
using namespace std;

Stack::Link::Link(void* dat, Link* nxt) {
  data = dat;
  next = nxt;
}

Stack::Link::~Link() { }

Stack::Stack() { head = 0; }

void Stack::push(void* dat) {
  head = new Link(dat, head);
}

void* Stack::peek() {
  require(head != 0, "Stack empty");
  return head->data;
}

void* Stack::pop() {
  if(head == 0) return 0;
  void* result = head->data;
  Link* oldHead = head;
  head = head->next;
  delete oldHead;
  return result;
}

Stack::~Stack() {
  require(head == 0, "Stack not empty");
} ///:~
```

I haven't included his header file.  Now, all I am able to come up with so far is something like this:

```
Stack::Stack(void** vp, int size) {
    head = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) 
        this->push((void*)vp[i]);

}
```

I try to then run it with:

```
#include "Stack.h"

using namespace std;

struct product {
    char ch;
    float price;
};

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    product p1, p2, p3, p4;
    p1.ch = 'a'; p1.price = 1.1;
    p2.ch = 'b'; p2.price = 1.2;
    p3.ch = 'c'; p3.price = 1.3;
    p4.ch = 'd'; p4.price = 1.4;

    product* ptr1 = &p1;
    product* ptr2 = &p2;
    product* ptr3 = &p3;
    product* ptr4 = &p4;

    product* ptr_arr[] = {ptr1, ptr2, ptr3, ptr4};
    Stack st(ptr_arr, 4);
```

and I get the error cannot convert from product** to void**.  Should I not be using a void** as my argument to the constructor?  How else can I pass an array that contains pointers to an unknown data type, in this case the struct Product?  The thing is that when I simply cast from product** to void** in main, without using Stack at all, I run into no problems, so I assument the error is actually in my "constructor".
As I said, I am a beginner to C++, and it could be that I am making some very simple error, but I cant seem to figure out how else I could go about this.  Thanks to all in advance, any help would be appreceated!

Comment: You should probably not be using void pointers for *anything* but memory allocation in C++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `void*` to point to anything, but a `void**` is not a
`void*`; it points to a `void*`.  And a `product*` is not a `void*` (it
could even have a different size or representation).  If you want to
pass a pointer to an array of pointers, you need to pass it with the
type of the pointers in the array, and if you want to use `void**`,
you'll have to have an array of `void*`.

It's not clear to me what relationship your code has to the original,
nor even what you are really trying to do.  (`Stack::Stack` is a
constructor.  For what class?)

Comment: The exercise states that I should implement a new Constructor for a Stack object...i.e. it belongs to the Stack class, and it is one which takes the arguments array* and int size, and this "constructor" should then fill the stack with the pointers to objects. How can I go about doing this then when I have a user-defined type such as Product?  Thanks for the replies btw!

Comment: If the constructor takes a `void**`, you have to pass it an array of `void*`.  The elements in the array can be initialized with the addresses of any type; e.g. `void* initValues[] = { &p1, &p2, &p3, &p4 };`

Comment: That makes perfect sense! Thank you. I should have figured that out from your first comment...I do have one question though...is this conceptually correct?  I mean, regardless of the fact that it works, is this how one would store pointers to objects of unknown type, or is there a better way?  I see many people saying I shouldnt use void pointers, but what would the alternative be?

Comment: @user999318 In this case, there isn't an alternative, since the class assignment says to use them.  Generally, however, void pointers represent a loss of type information, and you should design your code to keep as much type information as possible.  Depending on the context, templates or inheritance may provide a better solution; in other (rarer) cases, things like `boost::variant` are appropriate.